# объясните по действиям выражение, пожалуйста. F#

Tags: f#

объясните по действиям выражение, пожалуйста. F#

```
let rec fact n = iff ((=) n 1) 1 ((*) n (fact ((-) n 1)));;
```

Comment: Открыл [чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50036/f) по F#, поэтому если у вас возникнут какие - либо вопросы, то не стесняйтесь спрашивать. Просто сделайте мне пинг в чате (даже если не буду онлайн) и я при первой возможности отвечу.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ключевое слово `let` определяет имя для чего-нибудь. Чаще всего оно определяет имя для значений:

```
let x = 5      // числу 5 даём имя "x"
let y = "abc"  // строке "abc" даём имя "y"
```

На русский язык `let` переводится примерно как "пусть" (в математическом смысле):

```
пусть х = 5
пусть y = "abc"
```

Отдельный случай - определение имени не для значения, а для функции. В этом случае сразу за словом `let` указывается имя функции, а за ним - параметры, разделённые пробелами:

```
let f x = x + 5
```

Эта строка определяет функцию `f`, у которой есть один параметр `x`, и значение функции вычисляется путём прибавления пяти к значению параметра.

Ключевое слово `rec` в таком определении означает, что функция рекурсивная - то есть при высичлении её значения используется она же сама. Например:

```
let rec f x = if x = 1 then 1 else x*(f (x-1))
```

Эта функция имеет значение `1` когда параметр `x=1`, а в прочих случаях её значение вычисляется путём вызова самой этой функции с аргументом на единицу меньше.

В теле вашей функции используется другая функция `iff`. Эта функция отсутствует в стандартной билиотеке F#, так что я могу лишь предположить, что она определена где-то выше по коду.

У этой функции три параметра:

- `(=) n 1`
- `1`
- `(*) n (fact ((-) n 1))`

Второй параметр - это просто константа "1", ничего интересного. А вот первый и третий параметры - это выражения, в которых функции-опреаторы вызываются в префиксной записи (а не в инфиксной, как обычно положено операторам). В F# это допустимо и часто используется. Например, `(=) n 1` - то же самое, что `n = 1`. Оператор `=` здесь используется в префиксной записи, для чего он должен быть заключён в скобки. Аналогично:

- `(-) n 1` - то же, что `n - 1`
- `(*) x y` - то же, что `x * y`

Таким образом, сложная запись `(*) n (fact ((-) n 1))` - то же, что `n * fact (n-1)`.

Таким образом, вся ваша функция может быть переписана таким образом:

```
let rec fact n = iff (n=1) 1 (n * fact (n-1))
```

**Обратите внимание,** что эта запись с `iff` *не является* эквивалентом аналогичной записи с `if .. then`. Дело в порядке вычисления аргументов функций. В F# используется аппликативный порядок вычисления аргументов - то есть значения всех аргументов вычисляются перед вызовом функции. В данном случае это означает, что *оба* значения `n=1` и `n * fact(n-1)` будут вычислены *перед* вызовом функции `iff`, а это означает, что вызов `fact(n-1)` будет выполнен *в любом случае*, независимо от того, истинно выражение `n=1` или нет. Это приведёт к бесконечной рекурсии, и в итоге - к переполнению стека.

По форме выражения я предполагаю, что его автор ставил своей целью имитировать Lisp - отсюда и префиксная запись операторов. Вот примерно так эта функция будет выглядеть в Lisp:

```
(defun f (n)
   (if (= n 1)
       1
       (* (f (- n 1)))))
```

Но есть важное отличие: форма `if` в Лиспе, так же как и конструкция `if .. then` в F#, не является обычной функцией, а является так называемой "специальной формой". При обработке специальных форм компилятор поступает *специальным* образом - в частности, при обработке формы `if` компилятор не будет вычислять все три аргумента, а вместо этого вычислит сперва первый, а потом либо второй, либо третий (но не оба одновременно). Этого не случится в вашем примере, поскольку `iff` - просто обычная функция, что приведёт к переполнению стека.

Comment: Посоветуйте, пожалуйста, литературу по F#

Comment: Если вы читаете по-английски, то https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/. Отличнейший ресурс, рекомендую его всем и каждому. Если вы не читаете по-английски, то рекомендую срочно научиться. В нашем деле без английского никак.

Comment: @ДмитрийЯрушин, на русском языке есть замечательнейшая книга Криса Смита - "Программирование на F#"

Answer (score 0):

По-человечески это будет выглядеть вот так:

```
   let rec fact n =
      if n=1 then 1
      else n*fact(n-1)
```

И если допишем `fact 5`, то он посчитает факториал 5.

дошло до меня)

Comment: Это не совсем так, и отличие весьма критично. См. мой ответ, точнее последнюю его часть.